# How to modify the spectrum spike

Tags: matlab

[image][image][image]I have created a `.wav` file that contains frequency components from 8khz to 16khz. After, I use a recorder to record the sound (from the speakers). Finally, I use a MATLAB program to convert the sound into a figure.  This figure is shown below

[image]

In this figure, you can see a 8-16khz platform (which is what I want), but also you can see some spikes (pointed by the arrow). I don't know why the spikes are generated. Are they being generated in my code? The code I wrote is shown below.  Thank you

```
Fs =44100;     *sample frequence
toneFreq1 = 8000; %frequence
nSeconds = 25;  %time
f1 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq1*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq2 = 8100; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f2 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq2*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
....

toneFreq80 = 15900; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f80 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq80*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));
toneFreq81 = 16000; 
nSeconds = 25;  
f81 = sin(linspace(0, nSeconds*toneFreq81*2*pi, round(nSeconds*Fs)));


f_12345678910...= [f1+f2+f3+f4+f5+f6+f7+f8+f9+f10...f81]/81;


f_z=[f_12345678910...];
sound(f_z,Fs) 
wavwrite(f_z, Fs, 24, '8_16zKHz.wav');
```

Comment: .... dear God.  Are you telling me that your script has 81 differently named variables that contain signal information?  Can't you at least loop and accumulate the results together?  That code is unmaintainable!  In any case and in all seriousness, you are simply adding a bunch of sinusoids together, so those "spikes" that you are noticing could just be a by-product of different sinusoids at multiples of a fundamental frequency.  Consider something like adding `sin(t)` and `sin(2t)`.  At certain time points, the amplitudes match up and they will add together, doubling the amplitude.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you want to write the `wav` file to file, then use a recording program to record the sound, then plot the waveform.  You already have the signal in your workspace once you created it.  Can't you just plot that by itself?  What is the point of determining its plot after you're through a bunch of lossy steps? (i.e. the saving of the file using WAV compression, then recording its output... also using further compression)

Comment: It's hard to tell, but this code might be the same as your `f_12345678910...`, `tones=8000:100:16000;M=arrayfun(@(k) sin(linspace(0,nSeconds*tones(k)*2*pi,nSeconds*Fs)),1:length(tones),'UniformOutput',false);F=sum(cell2mat(M.'));`

Comment: @David - I agree with you there.  The tone frequency seems to be increasing by 100 each time.  That's the approach I would have done as well.

Comment: @David,rayryeng: Thank you for suggestion. I am a new hand for Matlab. My teacher told me to create a 8-16khz wave. I am not know well about the code(such as arrayfun). So I only can create single frequence(such as 8,9,..16khz)and I combine them by the above code. For why I use a recording program to record the sound and plot the waveform, because I want to get a wave(24bit 192khz)which can obtain from the recorder.

Comment: @David  I use the code you provide me, it is quite simple but well. But there is a little problem. I use my code to create a wav and convert it into a figure, you can see a broad of frequences. But when I use your code, it can not; whether it needs some little modify? Thankyou.  BTW. in my code, I use '/81'.

Comment: @David The figure 115b is for my code, while the figure 115c is for yours. Whether it needs some modify? Thank you.

Comment: @David   It is like the figure which i don't use the code('/81') previously.

Comment: @David,rayryeng:  I use the code Davide offered me, but the spike was still exsit. 154.JPG.

Comment: This is very odd way to create a signal. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you need to create a sum of sinusoids or is a broadband signal good enough? In any case, why not generate the signal at 192KHz and write it with `wavwrite` in 24bit precision?

Comment: To ThP: can you give me related code? Thank you.